# C# generics problem

Tags: c#, generics

I have a method (see below)

```
    public T ExecuteScalar<T>(string sSql, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sSql))
        {
            DataAccess dal = new DataAccess(ConnectionString);
            DebugOutput_SQL(sSql, parameters);
            object value = null;
            value = dal.ExecuteScalar(sSql, parameters);

            if (value != null && value != DBNull.Value)
                return (T)value;
        }
        return default(T);
    }
```

and I call this

```
 int32 WorkFlowID = DataProvider.ExecuteScalar<Int32>(sSql);
```

then it give me a error "Don't unbox to value" in line "return (T)value", any suggestion for this.

Comment: Can we see DataAccess.ExecuteScalar() method?

Comment: Is the error from some kind of VS addin?

Answer (score 4):

"Don't unbox to value" sounds like an odd error message. Is that exactly what it said?

My *guess* is that `ExecuteScalar` was returning a different type (`long`, `double` etc) rather than `int`. Try logging `value.GetType()` before you convert to `T`.

Just as a side-note, this:

```
object value = null;
value = dal.ExecuteScalar(sSql, parameters);
```

would be simpler (IMO) as:

```
object value = dal.ExecuteScalar(sSql, parameters);
```

There's no need to put it in two statements here.

EDIT: Just to clarify, the reason it's failing is that when you unbox a value, you have to unbox to the *actual* type, not just one which has a conversion available. For example, if you want to get an `int` out eventually, you could do:

```
int x = (int) (decimal) value;
```

which would unbox to `decimal` and then convert the `decimal` to an `int`. In this case though, I'd just specify the right type to start with if possible :)

Comment: Thanks Jon, you are right, I checked value that is decimal type.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your reasoning is right, but it's probably worth putting in an explanation that value types will only be unboxed to the exact type specified (e.g. you cannot unbox an int into a long even though the type conversion is implicit).

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
public T ExecuteScalar<T>(string sSql, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sSql))
    {
        DataAccess dal = new DataAccess(ConnectionString);
        DebugOutput_SQL(sSql, parameters);
        object value = null;
        value = dal.ExecuteScalar(sSql, parameters);

        if (value != null && value != DBNull.Value)
            return (T) Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
    return default(T);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the value object that you receive is a Nullable in which case you could do

```
return ((Nullable<T>)value).Value;
```