# Cast to int on SqlCommand-ExecuteScalar error handling

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I have code that is possibly fragile. This statement here

```
 int countDis = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

If I change the stored procedure to not return ANYTHING, then that casting to `(int)` is going to blow up. If I simply remove it, then I cannot compile.

What is the best code practice for defensive coding in this situation?

Comment: Use [Nullable types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) like `int?`

Comment: You can check these: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3829494/447156 and http://blogs.msmvps.com/ryan/2007/01/28/generic-executescalar-method/

Comment: If you change the stored procedure to return nothing, then you'd be better off using `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`, I think.

Comment: I changed it only for testing,  it is supposed to always be returning a number count  int

Comment: SQL Server stored procedure cannot return anything other than an `int` as their return value - so this is really not a problem...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just change the code as:

```
int countDis = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

This will ensure that even if `ExecuteScalar` returns `null`, as result of not selecting anything in stored procedure, `countDis` will have a value of `0`. Because `Convert.ToInt32(null) = 0`.

**Update** (10/12/2018)

Safer version. Thanks @Moe for highlighting `DBNull` case.

```
object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
result = (result == DBNull.Value) ? null : result;
int countDis = Convert.ToInt32(result);
```

Comment: ExecuteScalar can return DBNull.Value if there was a row in the result set, but the value of the column is a database NULL. In such cases, an InvalidCastException will be raised with the above code. ExecuteScalar can return null (i.e. C# null) if there were no rows in the result set from which to extract a column value.

Answer (score 6):

I usually use nullable types. e.g. :

```
string str;

int? countDis = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as int?;
if (countDis == null)
   str = "count is null";
else
   str = "Count is : " + countDis.Value;
```

This will work for whether ExecuteScalar returns null or DBNull.Value.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the scalar value before cast.

```
var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
int countDis =result != null ? int.Parse(result) : 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Because ExecuteScalar can return DBNull, the best way there I found is:

```
 var result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
 int countDis = result != null ? Convert.ToInt32(result) : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you treat a result of `DBNull.Value` as the same as `null` in that they should both be `0`, you can use a single line, though you're still using a temporary variable. I won't speak of execution speed:

`int countDis = int.TryParse(cmd.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString(), out int temp) ? temp : 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use to get as Object, and check its type then take your decision:

```
        object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(string))
        {
            //you can do your stuff with STRING
        }
        else if (obj.GetType() == typeof(int))
        {
            //you can do your stuff with INT
        }
        else
        {
            //add here ANYOTHER type you many want in future...
        }
```

Comment: Agile methodologies would say that you should be just coding for the current problem. This is also known as the YAGNI (You Ain't Gonna Need It) principle.

Comment: Sure, I also personally not prefer this, but just put here to give an idea for @MillRunner